# how to extract flash video from qwiki page

Tags: flash

I am developing an application on android and I want to embed the flash video of qwiki pages within a webView. How can I have access to the flash video of a qwiki page for a particular topic? I cannot find the embedded flash file at page info. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand what's a qwiki flash file. You mean the full presentation? Maybe i'm suggesting the obvious, but have you had a look at [the qwiki official api page](http://www.qwiki.com/api) ?